# T-Mobile Comet Android USB debugging connection to Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, usb, driver

Environment:
Windows 7 Ultimate SP1
Java JDK 6
Eclipse Helios
Android SDK (including Google USB Driver package, revision 4)
Android Development Tools (ADT)
T-Mobile Comet with Froyo (Android 2.2)
Comet has the following under Settings/Applications:
Unknown sources
  Allow installation of non-Market applications - enabled
Development:
  USB debugging - enabled
  Stay awake - enabled
  Allow mock locations - enabled

I can create and run a "Hello Android" application using the emulator in Eclipse. I can also set breakpoints and debug.

However, I cannot get Eclipse to recognize the Comet. The Comet does not appear to be completely recognized as a USB device by Windows 7.

More info:
The Comet itself shows USB debugging connected and USB connected.
When I connect the Comet to the Windows 7 Dell workstation, it shows that 4 out of 5 drivers are installed and ready to use, as follows:
USB Composite Device Ready to use
USB Mass Storage Device Ready to use
Comet No driver found
Comet USB Device Ready to use
Comet USB Device Ready to use

In Windows Explorer, the Comet shows as a an attached device with the title "Mobile Partner".

I try to point the Comet entry under the Device Manager to the Google USB Driver package, but I receive an error "Windows was unable to install your Comet - Windows could not find driver software for your device"

Further, under "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media", the Comet entry is grayed out.

As described elsewhere, I have tried using USBDeview to scrub the driver entries, followed by HTC Sync to view the device, but HTC Sync reports "No device connected"

So, what else can I try to get Windows 7 to recognize my Comet?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to get a driver for the Comet I actually had to download an entire program to get my Samsung Galaxy phone to work with my computer because the driver was not available on it's own.

Comment: Perfect! It turns out the needed driver was right on my Comet!

Answer (score 1):

To amplify my comment to Kingpin's suggestion, I belive that currently the right way to think about an Android hardware device USB debugging connection to Windows 7 is to focus on getting a driver to connect the Android device to Windows 7. There are new devices being introduced regularly, and the Android SDK support for those new devices will lag their introduction. It is likely that many folks will not be able to use the "stock" method of using the Google USB Driver package.

In my specific case, the T-Mobile Comet had the needed Windows 7 (x64) drivers stored on the device itself, so pointing to the "drivers" folder on the Comet was all I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yep Kingpin is correct I connected the device and a new drive G: apeared with two folders: Documents & Drivers. I followed the instructions: http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Guides/Set_up_Device_for_Development

and pointed to: G:\drivers\adb_driver instead of C:\android-sdk-windows\usb_driver

My machine now recognizes my Comet. Nice!

Thanks kingpin